# How to synchronize to match data from the mysql database with the internal sqflite database?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm new to flutter.
I want to sync local sqflite database from external mysql database. What is the best way

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a function in Firebase Functions to send data from each table. And I would try to make the fields in both tables with the same names as much as possible as a way to facilitate maintenance